# Order book question

Tags: limit-order-book, orderbook

This is a really simple question but I can’t figure it out. I was given this definition for trades in an order book. “A bid and an offer whose prices are the same or cross will pair, resulting in a trade. We consider bid and offer prices to cross when the bid price is higher than the offer price; in those cases, a trade will occur at the price of the older order”

I’m a little bit confused about the price point at which the trade occurs when there is a cross. For example, if the order book contained an offer of 100 dollars for 10 shares. If a bid comes in that is 105 dollars for 10 shares. Would the trade occur at 105 dollars or 100 dollars? I feel like it should be 105 dollars but I’m not sure what the older order means. Would the offer of $100 be considered the older order since it’s already in the book?

Comment: Yes, $100 because it's the passive order.